# Spring Security custom filter registration with Java config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to setup pre-authentication authorisation using Spring Security, similar to site minder where an external system does the authentication and saves login information in a cookie. However for that to happen I need to redirect to the external URL.

I tried doing it from an implementation of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` but that doesn't work because the `HttpServletResponse` object is not available.

A more appropriate way seems to be to just add a custom filter that checks for cookie and does the redirection and once the cookies are available then passes the control forward to Spring Security filter. How can I register this custom filter in a Java configuration based Spring Security application? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way is to redirect user to the external authentication interface using an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, for example `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`. The entry point is automatically invoked by Spring Security whenever it determines that user needs to get authenticated.

Once user returns back to your application, it should hit a custom filter which extends the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and extracts the username from your cookie/header/token (after perhaps some validity and integrity checks) in method `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal`.

The Spring configuration could be similar to:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="externalAuthentication">
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="cookieAuthentication"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="externalAuthentication" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="http://server.local/authenticationService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cookieAuthentication" class="custom class extending org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    ...
</bean>
```